# On using a CSV config with JSON data the quotes are read incorrectly for the key value pair

Tags: jmeter

I have a POST data from CSV used in excel

```
{"Name":"","Token":-1,"TimeScheduleToken":"1","AccessRule":[{"ObjectToken":"528","ObjectName":"Common_ wash_Room_Exit","RuleToken":"528","RuleType":2,"StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"ArmingRightsId":null,"ControlModeId":null}]}
```

When performing a post-execution the JSON data in the request is not as same as from the CSV. Find the request in the image

[image]

Quotes given for the key value pair is doubled up and showed in the request. How to resolve this, kindly suggest

Comment: This worked out for me, Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Vittal,

I have tried to reproduce your issue in JMeter 3.3 and noticed that its working fine. Please find below the settings that you need to do in 'CSV Data Config' element.

[image]
[image]

Moreover, I would recommend that when you are creating any csv file for the data then open the notepad and enter your data and then save it as .csv file to avoid any unnecessary elements/characters in the data.

You can also refer to the blog post to get more information on API load testing using JMeter: [JMeter Load Testing Against APIs](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/02/jmeter-load-testing-against-public-apis-bing-use-case/)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea regarding how you're getting these double quotation marks, however here is how you can remove them in the runtime:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def originalData = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
   def normalizedData = originalData.replaceAll("\"\"","\"")
   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",normalizedData,"")
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```
3. That's it, the JSR223 PreProcessor will replace all occurrences of double quotation marks with single quotation marks.

`sampler` is a shorthand to parent sampler class implementation, in case of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler it would be [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html), see class documentation for all available functions and properties.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.